# In Docker, bind mounting the nscd socket breaks gethostbyname

Tags: docker, ldap

I have a dockerized application that requires the nscd socket from the docker host. So I bind mount the socket at run time. DNS, `getpwnam`, `getpwuid`, etc. all work fine. Strangely though, I have found that `gethostbyname` doesn't work anymore. For example:

```
docker run --rm -v /var/run/nscd/socket:/var/run/nscd/socket ubuntu hostname -i
hostname: Name or service not known
```

However, under alpine, it does work:

```
docker run --rm -v /var/run/nscd/socket:/var/run/nscd/socket alpine hostname -i
172.18.85.4
```

Does anyone know why this breaks`gethostbyname` and how to fix it?

Update: if I use the same glibc on the host and container, it still breaks:

```
ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
docker run --rm centos ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
docker run --rm -v /var/run/nscd/socket:/var/run/nscd/socket centos hostname -i  
hostname: Name or service not known
```

Comment: And I bet it has something to do with gethostbyname only knowing about `/var/run/nscd/socket` when implemented by glibc. Alpine doesn't use glibc, it uses musl instead, and I believe the musl implementation of gethostbyname does not refer to nscd

Comment: Also note that nscd is unstable across glibc versions so mounting it might not be the best idea, because the container might be using a different version of glibc

Comment: Updated the question. Same issue when using the same OS/glibc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the LOCALDOMAIN to nothing works:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/nscd/socket:/var/run/nscd/socket --env LOCALDOMAIN='' centos hostname -i
```